# WMI desktopmonitor показывает только один монитор

Tags: cmd, wmi, монитор

Хочу получить все мониторы, сейчас у меня подключено два, 1 по dvi и 1 по hdmi, оба к видеокарте, но показывает только один. Проверил на втором компе, та же ситуация. Мне главное их ID, может надо в каком - нибудь другом WMI классе смотреть это?
Запросы делал из cmd - wmic, но вообще из своей программы делаю запросы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несколько лет назад писал скрипт для вычисления серийного номера дисплея и года производства. Это нужно было для инвентаризации. Главное, что я помню, - я не доделал его. Какого-то функционала не хватало, кстати, может и обработки многодисплейной конфигурации. Поэтому, если не лень, попробуйте разобраться в коде.

```
@for /f %%i in ('@wmic path win32_desktopmonitor get pnpdeviceid ^|@find "DISPLAY"') do @set val="HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\%%i\Device Parameters"


@reg query %val% /v EDID>NUL
@if %errorlevel% GTR 0 @echo BAD EDID&EXIT
@for /f "skip=2 tokens=1,2,3*" %%a in ('@reg query %val% /v EDID') do @set edid=%%c

@set /A Y=%edid:~34,1%*16+%edid:~35,1%+1990
@echo.Manufactured: %Y%

@set id=%edid:000000FC00=#%
@for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=#" %%a in ("%id%") do @set id=%%b
@set id=%id:~0,22%

@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
@for /L %%i in (0,2,20) do (
@set p=!id:~%%i,2!
@if !p!==0A @goto nxt
@set m=!m!0x!p!
)
@echo on
:nxt
@forfiles /p %windir%\system32 /m shell32.dll /c "cmd /c @echo.Model       : !m!"
@endlocal

@set edid=%edid:000000FF00=#%
@for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=#" %%a in ("%edid%") do @set id=%%b
@set id=%id:~0,20%

@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@for /L %%i in (0,2,18) do @set sn=!sn!0x!id:~%%i,2!
@forfiles /p %windir%\system32 /m shell32.dll /c "cmd /c @echo.S.N.        : !sn!"
@endlocal
```

Comment: Спасибо за скрипт, он работает, но показывает только один монитор, также как и мой вариант. Мне кажется тут уже проблема в самом WMI

Comment: Проверил команду на 2-х мониторном компе: **wmic  path win32_desktopmonitor get name**  - все верно: запрос вернул 2 объекта. Просто в моем скрипте в первой же строке возвращает ссылку в реестр на ветку с параметрами монитора. А поскольку это в цикле, то всегда  команда возвращает лишь **последнее** значение из списка мониторов. Надо лишь скрипт переделать в начале. Честно признаюсь мне сейчас лень.